# How extract data from $_SESSION created array

Tags: php

In the first HTML + PHP page I use the following command:

```
$_SESSION['myarray'] = $rows;
```

where `$rows` is an array.

In the next page I am trying to retrieve data from the array:

```
$dhoondo = $_SESSION['myarray'];
foreach ($dhoondo as list($ntag, $strTitle))
{
    echo $ntag, $strTitle;
}
```

But it shows "Array" instead of values, whereas `Var_dump($dhoondo);` clearly displays the data, even `$arrlength=count($dhoondo);` shows the exact number of items.

What's wrong?

The 
    var_dump($dhoondo);
result is array(20) { [0]=> array(13) { ["ISBN"]=> string(13) "9780849329500" ["TTAG"]=> string(5) "20752" ["TITLE"]=> string(76) "CRC HANDBOOK OF HIGH RESOLUTION INFRARED .......

Comment: Looks like the entries in your array are again arrays themselves …

Comment: show the results of `Var_dump($dhoondo);`

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
$dhoondo = $_SESSION['myarray'];
foreach ($dhoondo as $row)
{
    echo $row["TTAG"]." - ".$row["TITLE"];
}
```